# vuejs beforeunload http call event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have beforeunload event in vuejs, where I want to execute a http call which will check if the user is still logged in in the backend or their session expired.

But for some reason the event does not wait for the response and the call is being executed either way.
I have this:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
   SecurityService.checkUserActive()
         .then((value) => {
           if(value.data =='Active'){
               var form = debtService.buildRequestModelFromGlobalForm(this.parentForm, false);
                  if (this.isClientPortal) return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
                  else return;
           }
         })
         .catch(() => this.$router.push('unauthorized'));
});
```

Without the http call the alert is displayed as expected but with the http call it doesn't work as expected.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-router this might what you need: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow

The idea is you will do everything you want if ok then call next() method (beforeRouteLeave)

Example:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!');
  if (!answer) return false;
  else next();
}
```